# SMBv1 and Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, windows, smb

After recent ransom-ware flows in the wild we decide to disable SMBv on our WindowsServer. And after disabling it all my Ubuntu clients areunable to connect windows shares from that server.

My Ubuntu clients connect using SMB:\192.168.1.1\ShareName\

Is there any way to force Ubuntu to use other version of SMB. i.e. SMBV2 or V3?

Answer (score 0):

See

```
/etc/samba/smb.conf
```

and then `min protocol` option. But the default should already be SMB3.

Oh and you should not even be using shares if security is a concern.

See the [samba manual](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#SERVERMAXPROTOCOL) for more information on these settings.

Comment: Yes, I have added min protocol SMB3 there in Global Settings section. Although it was not there by default.

Comment: Yes, that's because the default is SMB3 according to the manual. And it should be avoided to add this parameter: when SMB4 gets released yours will not automatically switch to it

Comment: Ohh! Ok. So in that case my all Ubuntu systems should be able to connect windows shares and disabling SMB1 should not affect them.But its affecting. I replicated the same by disabling SMb1 on test server and  Ubuntu's not connecting to test server. So somehow those systems trying to connect using old version of SMB only.

Comment: Does the samba log show anything?

Comment: protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET - I believe it means windows server refusing the SMB v1 requests.